# Django create static and template directories when using startproject/startapp

Tags: python, django, git-fork

Is it possible to modify Django so the templates and static directories (including any subdirectories for existing apps) are created automatically?

I also want the settings.py to be updated to reflect any changes. That is, to have the lines:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates').replace('\\', '/')],
        ...
    },
]
```

and possibly a flag when running `./manage.py startapp` to add the appname to `INSTALLED_APPS`. I find I'm writing the same boilerplate code for each project and I feel like it could be easily streamlined.

Of course there might be a good reason why these things have been left out of Django. I assume that it's because the locations of those directories are only convention and they want to allow devs to easily move them if needed, but I've never needed to do this.

Ideally I'm looking for a fork of Django that would do this, so I wouldn't have to maintain it myself. I'm using Ubuntu, so I think I could alias the command to do those things, but I don't want to spend time doing that if someone else has already done it better.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at --template in the startproject documentation.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#startproject

Comment: Thanks! That helps a bit. I can't believe I hadn't thought to look in the docs already. I'll keep looking to see if there are equivalent flags for `startapp`, etc.

Comment: I'm glad it helped! I believe there is something similar for startapp. There are also some starter templates on github. Just search for "Django starter template" and you should see a few.